# How to Extract data from HTML page using regex pattern in java

Tags: java, html, regex

I'm trying to extract data from an html page as to store them in a String array

In the HTML page values are shown like this

```
 <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="width: 14%;">88055</td>
                        <td style="width: 19%;" class="gris">Ville</td>
                        <td style="width: 33%;"><a href="repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/municipalite/88055/" >Amos</a></td>
                        <td style="width: 34%;"><a href="repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/mrc/880/" >Abitibi</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="width: 14%;">85080</td>
                        <td style="width: 19%;" class="gris">Village</td>
                        <td style="width: 33%;"><a href="repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/municipalite/85080/" >Angliers</a></td>
                        <td style="width: 34%;"><a href="repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/mrc/850/" >Témiscamingue</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="width: 14%;">87050</td>
                        <td style="width: 19%;" class="gris">Municipalité</td>
                        <td style="width: 33%;"><a href="repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/municipalite/87050/" >Authier</a></td>
                        <td style="width: 34%;"><a href="repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/mrc/870/" >Abitibi-Ouest</a></td>
                      </tr>
```

I need to extract only the string where the href = Municipality

witch means Amos ,Angliers , etc... and store them into an array of string

So far I have tried this and I'm lost

```
  public static final String EXPRESSION = "";//How to write the regex expression?
String [] data = new String [20]
    URL url = new URL("http://myur.com");


 BufferedReader in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        while ((ligne = in.readLine()) != null) {
          //What to write here? 
            }
            in.close();
```

P.S : I'm aware the best method is to use an HTML parser instead but I'm really forced to apply this way

Much appreciation ,

Bass

Comment: You have participated in the culture that led to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1394393).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this to hardcode match the url having `municipalite` and get the text inside wrt to `>` and `<` characters.

This is my data file:

```
 <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="width: 14%;">88055</td>
                        <td style="width: 19%;" class="gris">Ville</td>
                        <td style="width: 33%;"><a href="repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/municipalite/88055/" >Amos</a></td>
                        <td style="width: 34%;"><a href="repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/mrc/880/" >Abitibi</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="width: 14%;">85080</td>
                        <td style="width: 19%;" class="gris">Village</td>
                        <td style="width: 33%;"><a href="repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/municipalite/85080/" >Angliers</a></td>
                        <td style="width: 34%;"><a href="repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/mrc/850/" >Témiscamingue</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="width: 14%;">87050</td>
                        <td style="width: 19%;" class="gris">Municipalité</td>
                        <td style="width: 33%;"><a href="repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/municipalite/87050/" >Authier</a></td>
                        <td style="width: 34%;"><a href="repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/mrc/870/" >Abitibi-Ouest</a></td>
                      </tr>
```

Here is the java file:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        BufferedReader in  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("data")));
        String line="";
        Pattern p=Pattern.compile("href\\s*=\\s*(?:\"|').*municipalite/[^>]*>(?:<.*>)*([^<]*)<.*$");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            Matcher m=p.matcher(line);
            while(m.find())
                System.out.println(m.group(1)); 
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ javac test.java 
$ java test 
Amos
Angliers
Authier
$
```

Regular expression breakdown:

```
href\\s*=\\s*(?:\"|').*municipalite/[^>]*>(?:<.*>)*([^<]*)<.*$
```

1. `href\\s*=\\s*` matches href following by 0 or more spaces followed
   by `=` and then 0 or more spaces
2. `(?:\"|')` -> `(?:)` means a non capturing group i.e it matches
   single or double quotes but doesn't capture/remember it
3. `.*municipalite/` matches any char till `municipalite/` occurs
4. `[^>]*>(?:<.*>)*` matches any char that is not a `>` for the rest of
   the url and then matches `>`, then tries to match 0 or more (all
   optional) opening tags into a non capturing group using this `(?:<.*>)`
5. `([^<]*)` this group actually captures your string into group 1
6. `<.*$` matches the rest of the line

Comment: why aren't you using `.*?>`, greedy instead of `[^>]*`?

Comment: if you use greedy matching it would match up to the last `>` skipping the in between text which we dont want

Comment: @ritesht93 worked like a charm, thanks from the bottom of my heart

Comment: @ritesh93 I meant to say non-greedy, `?` for non-greedy. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I have shown in python. But the regex is the same in Java, I believe. Use Java functions to find the matches.

```
import re
reg = r"<a href=.*?municipalite.*?>(.+?)</a>"
result = re.findall(html)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `".*\\bhref=\"repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/municipalite/\\d+/\"[^>]*>([^<]*)<.*"`

My demo code (below) gives console output:

**Console Output**

```
Amos
Angliers
Authier
```

**Demo Code**

```
public class HrefRegex
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final String[] sampleLines = new String[] {
            "  </tr>",
            "    <td style=\"width: 14%;\">88055</td>",
            "    <td style=\"width: 19%;\" class=\"gris\">Ville</td>",
            "    <td style=\"width: 33%;\"><a href=\"repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/municipalite/88055/\" >Amos</a></td>",
            "    <td style=\"width: 34%;\"><a href=\"repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/mrc/880/\" >Abitibi</a></td>",
            "  </tr>",
            "  <tr>",
            "    <td style=\"width: 14%;\">85080</td>",
            "    <td style=\"width: 19%;\" class=\"gris\">Village</td>",
            "    <td style=\"width: 33%;\"><a href=\"repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/municipalite/85080/\" >Angliers</a></td>",
            "    <td style=\"width: 34%;\"><a href=\"repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/mrc/850/\" >Témiscamingue</a></td>",
            "  </tr>",
            "  <tr>",
            "    <td style=\"width: 14%;\">87050</td>",
            "    <td style=\"width: 19%;\" class=\"gris\">Municipalité</td>",
            "    <td style=\"width: 33%;\"><a href=\"repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/municipalite/87050/\" >Authier</a></td>",
            "    <td style=\"width: 34%;\"><a href=\"repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/mrc/870/\" >Abitibi-Ouest</a></td>",
            "  </tr>",
          };


        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\bhref=\"repertoire-des-municipalites/fiche/municipalite/\\d+/\"[^>]*>([^<]*)<.*");

        for (final String s : sampleLines)
        {
            final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

            if (matcher.matches())
            {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! This helped me too